Any advice for creating jpop bass sound?
can someone help with getting bass tone like in this songs? What pedals and amps are usually used in this genre?






I have been playing bass for a while, but getting right tone is definitely my weak spot.

Might very well be a sampled bass actually. But pedals and amps are cool, but they do not matter that much for tone at first (also don’t think there is any effects stuff going on here). Try to understand how you can affect tone by technique, by plucking position, by pickup position, by equalizer settings. When you have a solid understanding of this you can extend you expression by using effect devices and stuff. But you can do a lot in terms of tone simply by the way you pluck.

Sorry, questions about gear recommendations or coping a certain sound aren’t covered here. If you’d like to edit to focus on technique and tone, that totally is.

@piiperiReinstateMonica  It may not be to your taste, but this is perfectly well-crafted, valid music.   Yes, the bass may be sampled, but we can discuss what it was sampled FROM!

Well for starters, if you're gonna play "J" rock, you need a "J" bass! (only half joking)

@Laurence I agree, it was a dumb comment.

You linked an entire album, so there's quite a few different tones in there, but I'll specifically address the tone in your second link.  A similar tone is used through the first album as well.
You can get a similar sound with most basses and most quality amps, though if you haven't already bought a bass, I'd recommend against a p-bass for this specific sound.  I've noticed that some modern active basses have a default tone similar to this, but active is not necessary.
Play fingerstyle, and pluck a bit closer to the bridge to tighten up the sound. Set your eq to imitate what you hear (it will probably involve a treble cut, and if you're not using an active bass, a high mid boost).  I also highly recommend a high pass filter to further tighten up the sound.  These examples seem to be high passed pretty aggressively, maybe even as high as 100Hz on some tracks.  Use a compressor with a fast attack and release (like the MXR M87) to flatten the dynamic range.

Hard to say without seeing the player, but it may be accomplished with good slapping technique, or a combination of slapping and a flanger pedal: The Breakdown: Slap Bass w/ Marcus Miller,, 3 Cool Slap Licks | Ida Nielsen, Marcus Miller, Mark King | Thomann
Flanger pedal: See (One of MANY):Boss BF-3 Flanger Bass Demo .

Where in the linked example did you hear slap?

To me it sounds like many of the bass parts are actually played with Yamaha DX-7 or similar sounding synthesizer. For the parts that are clearly played with a bass guitar, one way to achieve the sound is J-style bass with bridge pickup at full volume and possibly some neck in the mix for the scooped EQ curve, picked or plucked right next to bridge.
